# RecyclerView Adapter: how to fix "Private field mContext is assigned but never accessed"?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a RecyclerView list that appears to be working fine.
But Android Studio is a throwing a warning on "mContext" in the Adapter file, saying "Private field 'mContext' is assigned but never accessed".
But I assign it with "this.mContext = context;".
What am I missing here?

MyRecylerAdapter.java file

```
public class MyRecylerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private final Context mContext;   
    public ArrayList<ListItem> listItems;
    ...

    public MyRecylerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListItem> listItems) {
        this.listItems = listItems;
        this.mContext = context;  // Android Studio doesn't like this assignment.
    }
```

Comment: It means just what it says, you assign it, but you never actually use `mContext` anywhere.

Comment: @Pztar I am trying to understand how to access/fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> assigned but never accessed

You never **access**, you only **assign**

For example, this is an access. Something you'd do in a `ListAdapter` is inflate the layout.

```
View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.foo);
```

The real question: Why do you need the `Context` if you never access it?

Comment: RecylerView list is being created correctly so I'm wondering if I still need to access the context somehow.  Any thoughts?

Comment: The project will crash if there is context is removed as the MainActivity uses a MyRecyclerAdapter reference in "adapter = new MyRecyclerAdapter(MainActivity.this, list):

Comment: Again, why you think `MainActivity.this` is necessary? Your error suggest you don't need it as you never used it. It's your class, and you can fix the issue however you want...

Comment: I thought MainActivity.this was necessary and Context field too after reviewing RecyclerView articles, stackoverflow, etc, to see other examples that work.  Android rookie here.  Clearly I need to learn a lot more...

Comment: It's a habit carried over from ArrayAdapter. And if you don't need in your adapter class, then you don't need it in the constuctor. Not sure what you are reading, though. For example, not one here https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/recyclerview-part-1-fundamentals-for-listview-experts/